# add pointer elements to linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

Is there possible to make the code work without changing the main function? I have tried using `strcpy()` in the push function but it results in segmentation fault (core dumped).
This is the output currently:

```
ccc ccc ccc
ccc ccc ccc
ccc ccc ccc
```

The output should be

```
ccc ccc ccc
bbb bbb bbb
aaa aaa aaa
```

Code:

```
struct Node
    {
        char *data1;
        char *data2;
        char *data3;
        struct Node *next;
    };
```

```
   int main()
   {
       struct Node *head = NULL;
       char strings[3][10];
       char *s = "aaa";
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           strcpy(strings[i], s);
       }
       push(&head, strings);
       s = "bbb";
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           strcpy(strings[i], s);
       }
       push(&head, strings);
       s = "ccc";
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           strcpy(strings[i], s);
       }
       push(&head, strings);
   
       printList(head);
       freeList(&head);
   }

void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data[3][10])
{
   /* 1. allocate node */
   struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

   /* 2. put in the data  */
   new_node->data1 = new_data[0];
   new_node->data2 = new_data[1];
   new_node->data3 = new_data[2];

   /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
   new_node->next = (*head_ref);

   /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
   (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also don't post _pictures_ of text but post text as text.

Comment: "I have tried using strcpy in the push function". That would be more correct than what you have. What you have at the moment points all the nodes to the same `strings` so of course the result is only the last values copied into `strings`. Show your `strcpy` version if you want help with that. My guess is that you are not allocating memory for the `dataX` fields before calling `strcpy`.

Comment: Your structure contains _pointers_ to strings. All three structs pushed into the stack contain the _exact same_ pointers, that is pointers to `strings`.

Comment: ... or you might want this: `char *data1` -> `char data1[100]` etc. in the struct definition and `new_node->data1 = new_data[0]` -> `strcpy(new_node->data1, new_data[0])` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same `strings` over and over. You must allocate (in `push`) new arrays for each string. For example:

```
new_node->data1 = malloc(10);
new_node->data2 = malloc(10);
new_node->data3 = malloc(10);

strcpy(new_node->data1, new_data[0]);
strcpy(new_node->data2, new_data[1]);
strcpy(new_node->data3, new_data[2]);
```

Comment: OK. Please click the check mark on the left of my solution to indicate it helped you.

Comment: Just wonder do I need to loop through the data1,data2, data3 to free the list?

Comment: @wendy - Yes, for each call to `malloc()`, there should be a corresponding  call to `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that the pointers of the allocated nodes are all pointing to the same 3 memory locations: `strings[0]`, `strings[1]`, and `strings[2]`.

The statements:

```
new_node->data1 = new_data[0];
new_node->data2 = new_data[1];
new_node->data3 = new_data[2];
```

do not copy the strings to data1, data2, and data3 but rather store the memory addresses in them.

If you want to copy the strings contained in new_data[0], new_data[1], and new_data[2], you should allocate memory to data1, data2, and data3 and use the function `strcpy()` to do it.

example:

```
new_node->data1 = malloc(strlen(new_data[0]) + 1);
new_node->data2 = malloc(strlen(new_data[1]) + 1);
new_node->data3 = malloc(strlen(new_data[2]) + 1);

strcpy(new_node->data1, new_data[0]);
strcpy(new_node->data2, new_data[1]);
strcpy(new_node->data3, new_data[2]);
```